# Create dataframe using multiple other data frames based on specific criteria

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to find a smooth way of creating a new data frame based on specific criteria of other data frames.

I currently have multiple data frames. Examples are as follows.

```
data frame A:                  data frame B:                 data frame B:
i      j     Distance          i      j     Distance          i      j     Distance
10    -10       1              5      -20      10             5     -10       4
5     -10       2              5      -10       2            20      -20      3
15     -5       5              15     -10       1
```

I then want to make a data frame containing all the data from data frame A, B & C where i = 5 and j = -10. Hence the final data frame will be:

```
i     j     Distance
5    -10        2
5    -10        2
5    -10        4
```

I will be wanting to create multiple data frames based on different values of i and j so anything that is easily adaptable would be great!

Thanks,
Fiona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We place the datasets in a `list` and do the subsetting

```
library(tidyverse)
list(A, B, C) %>% 
           map_df(~ .x %>% 
                     filter(i==5, j== -10))
```

---

Or we `rbind` all the datasets together and use `subset`

```
subset(rbind(A, B, C), i ==5 & j == -10)
```

and with `tidyverse`, the way would be

```
bind_rows(A, B, C) %>%
            filter(i == 5, j == -10)
#  i   j Distance
#1 5 -10        2
#2 5 -10        2
#3 5 -10        4
```

#### data

```
A <- data.frame(i = c(10, 5, 15), j = c(-10, -10, -5), Distance = c(1, 2, 5))
B <- data.frame(i = c(5, 5, 15), j = c(-20, -10, -10), Distance = c(10, 2, 1))
C <- data.frame(i = c(5, 20), j = c(-10, -20), Distance = c(4, 3))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for multiple different ways to do this :) I've used the subset(rbind(A,B,C), i==5 & j ==-10) and it works a treat. Very simple piece of code, so thank you once again :D